# RxJava Debounce onNext()

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I'm trying to debounce clicks/swipes for my SwitchCompat with no success. 
The below code looks fine, though onNext isn't going through debounce() ie: When a user spams the switch, onNext is being called for every click, not being omitted due to debounce.

It should be working, this a bug with RxJava?

```
    timer = Observable.create { subscriber: Subscriber<in Void>? ->
        super.setOnCheckedChangeListener { buttonView, isChecked ->
            subscriber?.onNext(null)
        }
    }
    timer.debounce(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
```

Comment: just to clear one thing: Do you know debounce works with a timespan? To make debounce work you have to check and uncheck switch within 3 seconds according to your code. Try using a button for dummy purpose and check if it works.

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes i do and that's exactly what i'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Can you post your all code related to it? Because the code you have given does not explain your how are u trying to achieve it. It looks like you are creating a custom Swtich class and then doing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is your actual code I think the problem is not related to `debounce` at all. Like most Rx operators, `debounce` *returns a new Observable* - it does not change the one that `timer` is pointing to.

So, since you are not storing the reference returned by `debounce` anywhere, essentially nothing happens.

Try: `timer = timer.debounce(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)`

Comment: Thanks mate, that did the job!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [RxBinding library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) from Jake Wharton. It wraps android widgets into Rx. For you there is RxCompoundButton, which you can use like this:

```
RxCompoundButton.checkedChanges(switchCompat)
    .debounce(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Kotlin & [RxBinding Kotlin Version](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding). You can express in your custom CompoundButton

```
import com.jakewharton.rxbinding.widget.checkedChanges

class CustomCompoundButton: CompoundButton {
    constructor(context: Context): super(context, null)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?): super(context, attrs, 0)

    constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet, defStyleAttr: Int): super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, 0)

    fun throttledCheckedChanges() { 
        return this.checkedChanges().debounce(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }
    // OR
    val throttledCheckedChanges by lazy {
        this.checkedChanges().debounce(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    }

}

 // Use it in your activity/ fragment
 customCompoundButton.throttledCheckedChanges().subscribe { /* do sth */ }
 // OR
 customCompoundButton.throttledCheckedChanges.subscribe { /* do sth */ }
```

if you are NOT allowed to use [RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding) in your project. You should take a look [CompoundButtonCheckedChangeObservable.java](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/280882b29ac85861885df9880f65655ea4a31464/rxbinding/src/main/java/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/widget/CompoundButtonCheckedChangeObservable.java) for creating a Rx wrapper.